# Use “>>” Redirection Operator for Non-Existent File

Tags: shell

My code is:

```
#!bin/bash
n=1
for i in `ls 201*`
do
    if [ "$n" -gt 8 ]
    then
        awk -F "\x01" '{print $1}' $i | sort | uniq >> temp
        let "n++"
    else
        sort temp | uniq -c | awk '$1>3' | wc -l >> result.txt
        rm temp
        n=1
    fi
done
```

I want to count the number of people who appear more than three times in every week. The error message is:

```
sort: open failed: temp: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `temp': No such file or directory
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you check the permissions you have on the folder you're trying to run?

Comment: i = 0, and the else branch runs. Your if stmt depends on temp already existing.

Comment: @cdosborn You mean when using ">>", a file must exist if it is in a if statement?

Comment: No imagine you run the program, the first thing executed is the else stmt, it expects temp to exist. Your error is in `sort temp`

Comment: @cdosborn Got it. Thanks a lot. Such a stupid mistake. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing executed is the else stmt, it expects temp to exist. Your error is in `sort temp`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted `if [ "$n" -lt 8 ]` instead of `if [ "$n" -gt 8 ]`.

Only if n is *greater than* 8 you increase it, else you set it to 1. So you start in the "else" branch and never get to the "then".